# Not able to load 5gb csv file from cloud storage to bigquery table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a file size of more than 5gb on google cloud storage , I am not able to load that file to bigquery table.

errors thrown are:

1) too many errors
2) Too many values in row starting at position: 2213820542

I searched and found it could be because of max file size reached., so my question is how can i upload file having size greater than quota policy, plz help me. I have a billing account on bigquery.

Comment: Neither of the errors you report are to do with the size of the file: both relate to problematic content in it.

Answer (score 0):

5gb is OK. The error says for the row starting at position 2213820542, it has more columns than specified, e.g. your provided a schema of n columns, and that row has more than n columns after splitting.

Comment: well i got the issue , actually one of the filed is have description which contain double quite " which is throwing this error , but i want to know can i upload more than 5 gb file on big query table , thanks in advance